# Is there a way to select a while html element in netbeans?

Tags: html, netbeans

I'm working in netbeans 7.1 and I was wondering if there was a way to select a whole HTML element. ie a `div` tag.

Say I wanted to select div inner to to delete

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
      This is inner Content
    </div>
    Outer Content
</div>
```

Is there a way to select from `<div>` to `</div>` so I can just hit delete and remove the whole inner tag?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Click inside the inner div and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> (Select Next Element) and it will highlight all of the inner div.

If you extend the selection too far, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> (Select Previous Element) will retract the selection.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.... Although for some reason netbeans wasn't picking up the PERIOD. I had to go into character map and remap it. Could there be another period instead of the one that's next to the quesion mark?

Comment: Shouldn't be, but it may depend on your machine's keyboard map. On Linux I usually need to rebind things like <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Fn</kbd> because the window system wants to bind them for switching desktops. When that happens, NB never sees the key press.

Comment: When I do this shortcut with Netbeans on Mac, it simply prints out a special character. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @TheKarateKid keybindings are platform dependent. On Mac, open NetBeans preferences and select Keymap. Enter element in the search box a you will see the bindings for Select Next/Previous Element (Ctrl-Shift-Comma & Ctrl-Shift-Period)